# If $A^2$ is the zero matrix, why is $0$ the only eigenvalue of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A^2$ is the zero matrix, show that the only eigenvalue of A is $0$.

Comment: Suppose $a \neq 0$ were an eigenvalue of $A$.  What would it turn into in $A^2$?

Comment: Look at this geometrically. If $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$, then there is a vector $x$ with $Ax = \lambda x$, i.e. a vector which is simply *scaled* by $\lambda$ if $A$ is applied. If $\lambda$ is non-zero, that thus means that $Ax$ is non-zero also. Now apply $A$ again, i.e. look at $A^2x$. Can that be zero? Remember that $A$ is linear...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $Ax=\lambda x$, then $A^2x=A(Ax)=A(\lambda x)=\lambda Ax=\lambda^2x$.